# Probability events task

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I have to solve given task:
$$P(A\bar{B})=0,32 \\ P(\bar{A}B)=0,11 \\ P(A+B)=0,65$$

a) find $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(A|\bar{B})$

b) Have to tell does $A$ and $B$ are independent and explain why

I don't know how to solve it. I am familiar with basic formulas but not with compliments. Can you please help

Comment: drawing a Venn diagram usually goes a long way

Comment: I don't know how to draw that diagram also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

(Draw a Venn diagram to see this)

Denote $a = A \cap \bar{B}, b = B \cap \bar{A}, i = A \cap B, e = \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}$.

Then clearly, $a+b+e+i=1$ and your constraints impose $a = 0.32, b = 0.11$, and $a+i+b = 0.65$

Can you solve for the rest of the components? Note $P(A) = a+i, P(B) = b+i$ and then apply definition of conditional probability...

Comment: From what you type I see that $P(A) = 0.65 - (0.32+0.11) + 0.32= 0.54$, and $P(B)=0.22+0.11 = 0.33$ I can also say that $A$ and $B$ are depended because $P(A\cap{B}) \ne P(A).P(B) = 0.22 \ne 0.1782$ I don't know how you got to this

Comment: @TeodorKolev if you draw a Venn diagram (read entry on Wikipedia) it will help to see it...

Comment: but does my calculations correct?

Comment: @TeodorKolev yes, arithmetic is correct